# ReportBuilder2 + SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server

Should ReportBuilder 2 be capable of listing views when connecting to a SQL 2000 database?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand the question, you mean if its possible to retrieve data from a view in SS2000 from Report Builder 2.0? If thats the case then **yes**, it is possible to do it as far as I'm concerned. If your are having problems then it might be an issue with the data source credentials.